# Apply effect to video frame captured by camera

Tags: android, android-camera, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I noticed that there is `android.media.effect` for developer to use in api level 17. There is also a sample 'Helloeffect' for developer to render. However, the sample is focus on a picture. I read the file of effect class and found it must apply an effect to `GL` textures. I'm new on `opengl` and I want to apply an effect to the video frame captured by the camera.
 Can anyone give me some hints? Thanks!

Comment: Have you done this? applied effects to video using android.media.effects package? if yes, please can you post some sample code...

Comment: Please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31805837/applying-effects-on-video-being-played

Comment: are you building upon the 'Helloeffect' sample provided ?. If yes then just  convert the captured frame to a bitmap and replace it to the bitmap being used in the sample.

Comment: a little help -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22508276/in-android-is-it-possible-to-change-camera-from-front-to-back-and-still-keep

Answer (score 1):

you can make the parameter of camera, and then apply colorfilter to the parameter to get the different effect, but first you have to check the supported colorfilter for your device, basically it is device dependent.

```
Camera.Parameters p = camera.getParameters();

            camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters(); //this will provide the supporting parameter for your device.
             p.setSceneMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO);  //it will set the flash mode.
             p.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_NEGATIVE);  //it will set the color effect to the preview and recording videos.


            camera.setParameters(p);
```

but be careful with nexus device , i had checked this method into nexus 5, the camera preview was showing with effect, but recording was done as normal.

check it out, hope it will help.