# Recording a fragment or a view, output video

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-video-player, android-videoview, android-screen-support

***Scenario***

I have (an imageview and a videoview) or (something custom like a surfaceview and inside a photo to the left and to the right a video) inside a fragment and I need to output the fragment layout as a video, to join the photo and the video into a single video.

***Question***

I really don't know how to make this work, maybe to record the screen but is not proffesional. Maybe you can help me ? Some tutorials, ideeas or anything will be good.

Thanks.

Comment: Hmm.. as you can see i don't need a screen recorder.

Comment: I have to find a way to make a video from a photo and a video.

Comment: you can use ffmpeg library for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22508276/) is not for fragment, it helps you. You can make video with OpenGLES texture by 5.0 API.

or make screen recorder service. like this,

```
public boolean startRecord(MediaProjection mediaProjection, File file) {

    mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
    mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource..DEFAULT);
    mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
    mRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
    mRecorder.setOutputFile(file.getPath());
    mRecorder.setMaxDuration(60000);
    mRecorder.setVideoSize(720,1280);

    try {
        mRecorder.prepare();
        mMediaProjection = mediaProjection;
        Surface targetSurface = mRecorder.getSurface();
        mDisplay = mMediaProjection.createVirtualDisplay("ScreenRecorder", 720, 1280, 240,
                DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_AUTO_MIRROR, targetSurface, null, null);

        mRecorder.start();
        mRecording = true;
        showNotification();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

to get MediaProjection in activity

```
{
        btnStartRecording.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = mMediaProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent();
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_SCREEN_CAST);
            }
        });
}
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_SCREEN_CAST) {
            if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission denied, close this app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
            mMediaProjection = mMediaProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(resultCode, data);
            if (mMediaProjection == null) {
                return;
            }
            File moviesFolder = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES);
            File movieFile = new File(moviesFolder, "test.mp4");
            if (mService != null) {
                mService.startRecord(mMediaProjection, movieFile);
            }
            else{
                mMediaProjection.stop();
            }
        } else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
```

You can record everything on display.